# Vue way of writing HTML as a string variable / string template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In vanilla Javascript, we sometimes need to do the string HTML and it gets ugly. I was wondering if there is a way of making a `<template>` and assign it to a variable instead of writing something like

```
var myHtml = "<div class='row'>This is my text</div>"
```

Obviously, this example is short at won't hurt but consider when it gets very big.

Maybe something like:

```
var myHtml = `<div>This is good</div>`
```

or maybe

```
<template ref="myHtmlBlock">Text</template>

var myHtml = $refs.myHtmlBlock
```

The main aim is using variables inside the block so that I can say.

```
data() {
   return {
     myText: "Hello"
   }
} 

var html = `<div>{{ this.myText }}</div>`
```

Compared to:

```
var html = "<div>" + this.myText + "</div>"
```

Comment: probably looking for raw html https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to do the same using the double brackets inside html and have it bind to the component data. Did you ever find a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/

It does a good job of outlining your options.  Your best choice is based on project needs of course.

Recently, I've used the *X-Templates*.  It separates out the HTML content, which has its pros and cons:

- Pro: designers can get to it with out messing with your code
- Con: it's another file to include and manage

X-Templates worked well for me and seems to handle larger HTML coding.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up